# Angular 10 Not detecting changes when querying from an Akita store

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-akita

It's quite possible that I've set up my Akita store incorrectly but I have followed the docs pretty closely.

I'm setting some `routerLink`s to populate dynamically from a store (app behavior depends on updating routes as a user navigates)

Inside the subscription that returns the app state from which I derive my new routes, if I assign the returned object to my component parameter, I get the dreaded `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`

Weirdly, if I instead assign a static object to that property inside the subscription, I don't get the error (but the value is static, not what I need)

I was able to get it to work with `.detectChanges()` but my impression was that Akita handles change detection for us so I'm super confused (and would like to not have to manually detect changes every time I sub to a store query)

The code that works (in the nav bar):

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getRouteParams();
    this.appQuery.appState$.subscribe(next => {
      this.app = next;
      this.change.detectChanges(); 
      //setting this.app = a static object instead of the prior 2 lines also works "fine"
    });
```

The code that sets the state (in one of the navigable components):

```
  ngOnInit(): void {  
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.slug = params['slug'] ? params['slug'] : '';
        this.appService.updateTab('activeRosterSlug',this.slug);
      }
    )
  }
```

query.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Query } from "@datorama/akita";
import { AppState, AppStore } from './store'

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AppQuery extends Query<AppState> {
  constructor(private appStore: AppStore){
    super(appStore)
  }
  appState$ = this.select();
}
  }
```

store.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, StoreConfig } from '@datorama/akita';

export type AppState = {
  activeRosterSlug: string, 
  activeMatchSlug: string;
  activeEventSlug: string;
  activeManifestSlug: string;
  maximixed: boolean;
  footerExp: boolean;
}

export const getInitialState = () => {
  return{
    activeRosterSlug: '',
    activeMatchSlug: '',
    activeEventSlug: '',
    activeManifestSlug: '',
    maximixed: false,
    footerExp: false
  }
}

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
@StoreConfig({name: 'appStore'})
export class AppStore extends Store<AppState> {
  constructor(){
    super(getInitialState())
  }
}
```

service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AppStore } from './store';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AppService {
  constructor(private appStore: AppStore) {}

  updateTab(tabName: string, tabId) {
    let update = {}
    update[tabName] = tabId;
    this.appStore.update(update);
  } 
}
```

Comment: An news about this topic?

Answer (score 0):

Inject the query in your component and subscribe to it.

`constructor(private appStore: AppStore, private query: AppQuery) {}`

Make sure to avoid `this.change.detectChanges();`  as much as possible.
You can use it mostly in cases where strategy is `.OnPush`.

Query should emit a new value every time the state is updated.

**Update the state this way e.g.:**

```
updateTab(tabName: string, tabId: string): void {
        this.appStore.update((state: AppState) => {
            const newState = { ...state };
            newState[tabName] = tabId;
            return newState;
        });
}
```

**Usage in the component:**

```
this.query.appState$.subscribe((state: AppState)=> {
      // logic goes here
});
```